# how to split the long text with separation of " - " (update as name, title, company in sql

Tags: sql

Hi i need the query for below sample text to split into Name, title, company with separation of " - "

Example:-

Full Text

```
Do Yun-Kim - Project Manager - Pioneer Windows Mfg. Corp.
Chen-Yi Li - Solutions Consultant - Worldpay
Linda Hager - Presales - Kronos
Ryan Asher
Steve Collins - RVP Sales - Enterprise
Bruce Peck - Corolla  North Carolina
Phillip Bartling - Managing Partner - Your Fantasy League Partners
Perry Tran - Data Analyst - MobilityWare
Katherine Tran - Principal Quality Assurance Engineer - Western
Wayne Peters - WW Sales - Microsoft
Asrith Inuganti - Account Relationship Manager - Shine.com
Seth Catalli - Regional Vice President - UiPath
```

Output :-

```
Name              title                    company
Do Yun-Kim        Project Manager          Pioneer Windows Mfg. Corp.
Bruce Peck        Corolla  North Carolina
Linda Hager       Presales                 Kronos
```

[image]

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server an Postgres are two very different products. Which one are you really using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: What does it mean you want to query text? Is this text in a table? In one single cell (one column and one row)? Or in a column (one row per line)? Or not in a table yet at all?

Comment: @perusjosh . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

With Postgres this can easily be done using split_part:

```
select full_text, 
       split_part(full_text, '-', 1) as name,
       split_part(full_text, '-', 2) as title,
       split_part(full_text, '-', 3) as company
from the_table;
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried the above code, but am getting the following error, "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 16
'split_part' is not a recognized built-in function name." am using SQL 2014 version. can i get any suggestion to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL You can use parsename like this:

```
Declare @t table (input nvarchar(500))

Insert into @t values ('Linda Hager-Presales-Kronos')

select  PARSENAME(replace(input,'-','.'),3) as 'Name',
        PARSENAME(replace(input,'-','.'),2) as 'Title',
        PARSENAME(replace(input,'-','.'),1) as 'Company'
 from @t
```